# Converting CSV to JSON without ANT or Maven

Tags: java, javascript, json, apache-poi

I was trying to convert a CSV file to JSON format, but I have no idea about ANT or MAVEN. I have used Apache POI. I am trying to do this with Apache POI. Is there any other way to do that?

and this what I was trying to do, but getting following error 
--java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet

// Start constructing JSON.

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray rows=new JSONArray();

    for ( Iterator<org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row> rowsIT = sheet.rowIterator(); rowsIT.hasNext(); )
    {
        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row row = rowsIT.next();
        JSONObject jRow = new JSONObject();

        // Iterate through the cells.
        JSONArray cells = new JSONArray();
        for ( Iterator<Cell> cellsIT = row.cellIterator(); cellsIT.hasNext(); )
        {
            Cell cell = cellsIT.next();
            cells.put( cell.getStringCellValue() );
        }
        jRow.put( "cell", cells );
        rows.put( jRow );
    }
```

Comment: Yes, there is another way to do that. Question answered.

Comment: Please post your CSV header and I made the twenty lines of code for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple CSV can be converted to Json by simple java coding as follows

First load the file using

```
BufferedReader.readLine()
```

Then use

```
String.split(",") // to get the value from each line
```

And write each value to the output using

```
BufferedWriter //  with the necessary JSON braces and quoting
```

Comment: This method could easily lead to significant parsing errors. For example, the delimiter for records could be something else than `newline`. Also, there is the possibility of quoted/escaped delimiter chars. Quote characters on the other hand could be escaped, too within a quoted cell. I suggest using a sophisticated framework for this anyway.

Comment: @Sri What about the [Apache Commons library for CSV](http://commons.apache.org/csv/)?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for my problem, I read my CSV usig BufferReader and converted it to JSON by using 
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/